# inconsistency between complier generated copy constructors on padding

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I was using the visual studio 2019 Community version under x86. The compiler-generated Copy constructor using the bitwise copy sematic tends to copy the padding. while the compiler-generated copy constructor not using the bitwise copy sematic tends to ignore the padding. while the compiler-generated copy assignment operator always copies the padding.

To be specific:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int m_value;
    char m_word = 'a';
};
```

will have the 3 bytes padding copied.

```
class Foo {
public:
    IntContainer m_int;
    char m_word = 'a';
};
```

will not have the padding copied. `IntContainer` has a public member of an int and a user-provided copy constructor.

Is this a platform-specific or compiler-specific thing? What is the difference between this bitwise copy semantic versus memberwise copy on the assembly level?

Comment: Did you build a "release" build, or an unoptimized "debug" build?

Comment: You can’t write a conforming program that can tell the difference, so either way is fine. Even doing it different ways in the same program...

Comment: Presumably `IntContainer` isn't POD so different rules apply

Comment: Also, [see this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1ce98ed317ccc3c).  Look at the results when `std::is_trivially_copyable` is used to test.  Now, if the compiler reported that a class is trivially copyable, yet still did not do a bitwise copy (probably using `memcpy`), then that would be an issue.

Comment: @PeteBecker Wouldn't this be conforming: `char buf[sizeof(Foo)]; Foo f{1,'a'}; memcpy(buf, &f, sizeof(Foo));` and then read the copied padding bytes? Or is even the `memcpy` non-conforming because of reading uninitialized memory?

Comment: The release builds following the same pattern on my PC. It is true you can not have a practical program that tells the difference. However, these inconsistencies made the "Integrity of the base class subobject within the derived class" a thing Page 85 Inside the C++ object model third edition. In short, the derived class will have padding between the base class subobject and its data members, Instead of pack its data member directly after the base class subobject.

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- I don't want to dig into the details now; you may be right, but if so, it's in the details of when you can `memcpy` and when you can't. Mostly you can't; it's only for very simple types that you can. I haven't been paying attention as those baroque requirements have been changing.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, I was under the impression that it is ok to `memcpy` objects of complex types or `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&complex_object)` to inspect the byte pattern.

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- maybe; but having done that, the contents of the padding bytes are still unspecified. There is no requirement that they be consistent, even between two separate inspections of the same object. (Yes, that's a different approach from what I said earlier)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a platform-specific or compiler-specific thing?

As far as the language is concerned, it is language implementation specific. A compiler can make different choices depending on platform, and different compilers can make different choices for same platform.